# dnf error: Aborted (core dumped) after packages upgraded from .fc22.x86_64 to .fc22.i686 in fedora 22

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I have Fedora 22 XFCE in Oracle VM, yesterday I tried installing skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm, this tried upgraded many of the packages example: upgraded glibc-2.21-13.fc22.x86_64 to glibc-2.21-13.fc22.i686 mentioned below my dnf.rpm.log for more details. After this upgradation of multiple packages. dnf, yum, rpm got crashed and I keep getting **Aborted (core dumped)** error for dnf, yum, rpm any of the commands.

Please suggest how to fix this **Aborted (core dumped)** error.

```
 
[rbeli@localhost log]$ dnf update
Aborted (core dumped)
[rbeli@localhost log]$ yum update
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf update'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

Aborted (core dumped)
[rbeli@localhost log]$ yum history
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf history'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

Aborted (core dumped)
[rbeli@localhost log]$
```

Refered: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1315811

```
vi /var/log/dnf.rpm.log
Apr 26 14:30:19 INFO --- logging initialized ---
Apr 26 14:36:42 INFO --- logging initialized ---
Apr 26 14:40:55 INFO Upgraded: libgcc-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:40:56 INFO Upgraded: nss-softokn-freebl-3.23.0-1.0.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:13 INFO Upgraded: glibc-common-2.21-13.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:22 INFO Upgraded: glibc-2.21-13.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:23 INFO Upgraded: libstdc++-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:23 INFO Upgraded: libquadmath-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:24 INFO Upgraded: elfutils-libelf-0.166-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:26 INFO Upgraded: libstdc++-devel-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:57 INFO Upgraded: pcre-8.38-4.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:57 INFO Installed: sqlite-libs-3.11.0-3.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:58 INFO Installed: elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.166-1.fc22.noarch
Apr 26 14:41:58 INFO Upgraded: elfutils-libs-0.166-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:58 INFO Upgraded: systemd-libs-219-27.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:58 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-common-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:41:59 INFO Installed: nss-softokn-freebl-3.23.0-1.0.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:00 INFO Installed: glibc-2.21-13.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:01 INFO Installed: zlib-1.2.8-7.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:01 INFO Installed: libgcc-5.3.1-6.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:01 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-location-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:01 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-sensors-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:02 INFO Upgraded: libgfortran-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:04 INFO Upgraded: cpp-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:05 INFO Upgraded: libgomp-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:05 INFO Upgraded: dbus-libs-1:1.8.20-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:12 INFO Upgraded: systemd-219-27.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:13 INFO Upgraded: dbus-1:1.8.20-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:16 INFO Upgraded: glibc-headers-2.21-13.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:17 INFO Upgraded: glibc-devel-2.21-13.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:22 INFO Upgraded: gcc-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:22 INFO Upgraded: libquadmath-devel-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:24 INFO Upgraded: gcc-gfortran-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:25 INFO Upgraded: gcc-c++-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:26 INFO Upgraded: dbus-x11-1:1.8.20-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:26 INFO Installed: python2-systemd-231-4.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:26 INFO Installed: python3-systemd-231-4.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:27 INFO Upgraded: systemd-compat-libs-219-27.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:27 INFO Upgraded: libgudev1-219-27.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:31 INFO Upgraded: elfutils-0.166-1.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:31 INFO Upgraded: sqlite-3.11.0-3.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:33 INFO Upgraded: pcre-devel-8.38-4.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:33 INFO Upgraded: libstdc++-static-5.3.1-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:33 INFO Upgraded: libtiff-4.0.3-21.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:35 INFO Upgraded: mesa-libglapi-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:35 INFO Upgraded: mesa-libgbm-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:42:36 INFO Installed: libstdc++-5.3.1-6.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:36 INFO Installed: libpng-2:1.6.16-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:37 INFO Installed: libogg-2:1.3.2-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:37 INFO Installed: expat-2.1.0-10.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:37 INFO Installed: libjpeg-turbo-1.4.0-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:38 INFO Installed: alsa-lib-1.0.29-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:39 INFO Installed: libICE-1.0.9-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:39 INFO Installed: xz-libs-5.2.0-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:39 INFO Installed: libffi-3.1-7.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:40 INFO Installed: libgpg-error-1.17-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:40 INFO Installed: libgcrypt-1.6.3-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:40 INFO Installed: libwayland-client-1.7.0-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:40 INFO Installed: libwayland-server-1.7.0-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:41 INFO Installed: libxml2-2.9.2-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:41 INFO Installed: libvorbis-1:1.3.4-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:42 INFO Installed: dbus-libs-1:1.8.20-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:42 INFO Installed: bzip2-libs-1.0.6-14.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:42:42 INFO Installed: freetype-2.5.5-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:00 INFO Upgraded: fontconfig-2.11.94-4.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:43:07 INFO Installed: fontconfig-2.11.94-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:08 INFO Installed: sqlite-libs-3.11.0-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:08 INFO Installed: libcom_err-1.42.12-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:08 INFO Installed: keyutils-libs-1.5.9-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:08 INFO Upgraded: krb5-libs-1.13.2-14.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:43:10 INFO Installed: qtwebkit-2.3.4-6.fc22.x86_64
Apr 26 14:43:10 INFO Installed: libxslt-1.1.28-8.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:10 INFO Installed: libtheora-1:1.1.1-12.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:11 INFO Installed: flac-libs-1.3.1-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:11 INFO Installed: clucene09-core-0.9.21b-13.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:35 INFO Installed: pcre-8.38-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:35 INFO Installed: libselinux-2.3-10.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:37 INFO Installed: glib2-2.44.1-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:38 INFO Installed: gstreamer1-1.4.5-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:39 INFO Installed: mesa-libglapi-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:40 INFO Installed: cdparanoia-libs-10.2-18.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:44 INFO Installed: graphite2-1.2.4-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:46 INFO Installed: harfbuzz-0.9.40-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:46 INFO Installed: elfutils-libelf-0.166-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:46 INFO Installed: elfutils-libs-0.166-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:47 INFO Installed: cracklib-2.9.1-5.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:48 INFO Installed: libvisual-1:0.4.0-17.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:48 INFO Installed: orc-0.4.22-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:48 INFO Installed: proj-4.8.0-7.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:49 INFO Installed: pixman-0.32.6-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:49 INFO Installed: json-c-0.12-5.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:49 INFO Installed: libasyncns-0.8-8.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:49 INFO Installed: tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-80.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:49 INFO Installed: lcms2-2.7-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:50 INFO Installed: libmng-2.0.3-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:50 INFO Installed: jbigkit-libs-2.1-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:51 INFO Installed: libtiff-4.0.3-21.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:51 INFO Installed: libattr-2.4.47-9.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:52 INFO Installed: libcap-2.24-7.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:52 INFO Installed: gsm-1.0.13-12.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:52 INFO Installed: libsndfile-1.0.25-14.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:52 INFO Installed: libuuid-2.26.2-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:52 INFO Installed: libSM-1.2.2-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libwebp-0.4.3-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libXau-1.0.8-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libxcb-1.11-8.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libX11-1.6.3-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libXext-1.3.3-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:53 INFO Installed: libXrender-0.9.9-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:54 INFO Installed: libXfixes-5.0.1-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:54 INFO Installed: libXv-1.0.10-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:54 INFO Installed: libXi-1.7.4-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:54 INFO Installed: libXtst-1.2.2-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:54 INFO Installed: libXcursor-1.1.14-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:55 INFO Installed: libXdamage-1.1.4-6.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:55 INFO Installed: libXrandr-1.4.2-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:55 INFO Installed: libXft-2.3.2-2.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:56 INFO Installed: libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-8.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:56 INFO Installed: libXinerama-1.1.3-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:56 INFO Installed: libXxf86vm-1.1.4-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:57 INFO Installed: libpciaccess-0.13.3-0.3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:57 INFO Installed: libdrm-2.4.61-3.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:57 INFO Installed: mesa-libgbm-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:57 INFO Installed: mesa-libEGL-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:57 INFO Installed: libxshmfence-1.2-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:58 INFO Installed: mesa-libGL-10.6.9-1.20151008.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:58 INFO Installed: cairo-1.14.2-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:58 INFO Installed: libverto-0.2.6-4.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:43:59 INFO Installed: krb5-libs-1.13.2-14.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:00 INFO Installed: openssl-libs-1:1.0.1k-14.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:01 INFO Installed: qt-1:4.8.6-30.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:03 INFO Installed: qt-x11-1:4.8.6-30.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:03 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-common-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:04 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-location-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:04 INFO Installed: qt-mobility-sensors-1.2.2-0.17.20140317git169da60c.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:04 INFO Installed: audit-libs-2.4.2-1.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:04 INFO Installed: libdb-5.3.28-12.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:07 INFO Installed: pam-1.1.8-19.fc22.i686
Apr 26 14:44:07 INFO Installed: systemd-libs-219-27.fc22.i686
```

Comment: While an interesting problem (but frustrating for you), this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix-Linux) OR http://serverfault.com (professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: I saw the same thing today.  Google hasn't been kind, except to say that I'm not alone.  I burned the install disk a while ago and I've used it several times.  This is the first time I've seen the problem.  Something must have changed with the updates.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you hit the bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1314592, which is triggered by installing glibc.i686 *without first having the software on your system up to date*.

You could try the workaround given in [the bug you reference](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1315811#c22) work? That is, the one from "charles.unix.pro":

> Okay, I have a workaround that seems to restore functionality.
>
> I copied /lib64/libnspr4.so from a machine with nspr-4.12.0-1.fc23.x86_64 to the broken machine, did a ldconfig and a reboot.
>
> rpm and dnf no longer crash.
>
> -- Charles

but if that doesn't work, you might, unfortunately, be looking at a reinstall situation as your easiest bet. Sorry about that!

It's no help now, but the lesson is: **always apply updates *before* installing new packages**.

Comment: Thanks much Charles, for your quick response to my question. Let me try the one you suggested. what is Idconfig exactly?

Comment: Note that I'm not Charles. :) In any case, simply run the command `ldconfig`

Comment: thanks buddy. will try it out and will let you know if this works.

Comment: I tried the one you suggested, I still get the same error.